# Seven Segment display always shows top

Tags: arrays, for-loop, arduino

Using my Arduino, I created an two dimensional array with the hexadecimal numbers 0-F to display on a seven segment display. Everything works perfect, I used a for loop to make every segment of the display turn on, but the top display (A) is always on, even when it shouldn't be on.

```cpp
void sevenSegment(int a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < nPins; i++) {
    digitalWrite(fontArray[a][i], HIGH);
  }
}
```

Array:

```cpp
int fontArray[][7] = { 

  {13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8}, // 0
  {12, 11},               // 1
  {13, 12, 10, 9, 7},     // 2
  {13, 12, 11, 10, 7},    // 3
  {12, 11, 8, 7},  // 4
  {13, 11, 10, 8, 7},   // 5
  {13, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7},   // 6
  {13, 12, 11}, // 7
  {13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7},  // 8
  {13, 12, 11, 10, 8, 7},  // 9
  {13, 12, 11, 9, 8, 7},  // A
  {11, 10, 9, 8, 7},  // B
  {13, 10, 9, 8}, // C
  {12, 11, 10, 9, 7}, // D
  {13, 10, 9, 8, 7}, // E
  {13, 9, 8, 7} };  // F
```

Why is the top segment of the display (A), pin 13, always burning? :/

Answer (score 1):

Those segments are never set back to `LOW`.

You'll need something like:

```cpp
int fontArray[][7] = { 

  // pins: {13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7},  // 8

  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, // 0
  {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // 1
  // ...
};
```

And then use:

```cpp
void sevenSegment(int a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    digitalWrite(13 - i, fontArray[a][i]);
  }
}
```

In case the pinnumbers are not contiguous, a second array can be used like this:

```cpp
int pinArray[] = {13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7};

void sevenSegment(int a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    digitalWrite(pinArray[i], fontArray[a][i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: But then it will turn pin 1 on and off again rapidly. How do I link the values 1 for HIGH and 0 for LOW to an array with the corresponding pin numbers?

Comment: @goeie_billen There is no pin 1 being set anywhere. And HIGH is already 1 and LOW 0.

Comment: @goeie_billen `fontArray` now contains the values for the segments (1 for HIGH, 0 for LOW) for each digit. The loop counts down from pin 13 to pin 7 and sets the value found in `fontArray[a][i]`.

Answer (score -1):

Short of there being a bug in your wiring, the array `fontArray` does not explicitly initialize all values. So the compiler will give these uninitialized values (in a global array) a default of 0.

The result is calls to `digitalWrite(0, HIGH)`. Depending on the board and pin configuration then a pin "0" may map to 13.

The for loop can be written to guard against this with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nPins; i++) {
  int pin = fontArray[a][i];
  if (pin == 0) {
    break;
  }
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Assuming he is using the Uno, 0 is pin 0 (RX) not 13.